# Don't understand why nothing is being appending to list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have the following Python code:

```
import os

directory_test = []

for c in range (0,len(num_list),1):
    print("Hi, you are on num " + str(num_list[c]) + ".")
    if os.path.isdir(os.getcwd() + "//" + str(num_list[c])):
        None
    else:
       os.makedirs(name = os.getcwd() + "//" + str(num_list[c]), exist_ok=True)
       directory_test.append(os.getcwd() + "//" + str(num_list[c]))
    print(directory_test)
```

Why is my list, `directory_test`, empty? How can I populate it from the code in the `else` block?

Comment: The `"//`" is weird, though. What OS are you using? You probably want a single /.

Comment: It seems like `os.getcwd() + "//" + str(num_list[c])` could be the issue, as it appears that `os.path.isdir()` is returning `False`. Please show an example of what's being passed to `listdir`. Also what's with the double slashes? You could just use `os.path.join()` instead which is way easier. Also, that `None` there by itself is weird, you should instead use `pass` since that's what it's for.

Comment: Use [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to create the name.

Comment: why os.path.join()? I'm not arguing with you, but I am a noob and I am just curious / trying to learn.

Comment: From the doc I linked to: _"Join one or more path components intelligently. The return value is the concatenation of path and any members of *paths with exactly one directory separator following each non-empty part except the last, meaning that the result will only end in a separator if the last part is empty. If a component is an absolute path, all previous components are thrown away and joining continues from the absolute path component._"

Comment: So, I am an idiot, the directories were already created and since my directory was only appending in the else statement, that's why nothing appended to the list.